# TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
word = ord(input('any symbol, but only one:'))
bb = chr(word)
for num, value in word, bb:
    print(str(num) + '==>' + value)
```

почемуто выводит следущее:

```
any symbol, but only one:g
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\allscripts.py\workiii\jarvis.py", line 3, in <module>
    for num, value in word, bb:
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
```

Comment: А чего вы хотели сделать?

Comment: тут не так с `for num, value in word, bb:` - что это такое вообще? мы с питоном не понимаем! какая у вас вообще задача то была?

Answer (score 4):

Выражение `for num, value in word, bb:` означает, что нужно перебрать коллекцию и каждый ее элемент распаковать по переменным `num` и `value`.

В цикле `word, bb` станет кортежом на два элемента `word` и `bb`, т.е. сначала цикл вернет `word`, потом `bb`.

А значения `num, value` заставят его каждый элемент пытаться разложить на два элемента. А т.к. у вас `word` является числом, то для него такого нельзя сделать (`cannot unpack non-iterable int object`).

Кст, распаковка выглядит так, для рабочего варианта сделал обе переменных строками по два элемента:

```
word, bb = '12', '34'
for num, value in word, bb:
    print(num, '=>', value)
# 1 => 2
# 3 => 4
```

Как мы тут видим, сначала цикл вернул `word`, после значение `"12"` распаковал по двум переменным, а следующей итерацией вернул `bb` и сделал аналогичную распаковку

---

Мб, вам не цикл нужен был, а что-то вроде такого?

```
num, value = word, bb
print(str(num) + '==>' + value)
```